# using node to send emails without having to know my password

Tags: node.js

I am able to use node-mailer to send an email to myself but I'd feel more comfortable using something that does not require me to include my password in my code. I'm not even sure why the password is required but it does not work without it. I mean I can send an email to someone without their password so it seems like an app should be able to as well. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: You can't send an email to someone else if you don't know *your own* password, though.

Comment: One thing that would be good to know is [ask].

Comment: The email you're sending has to come from an email account, which means you need to know the password for that account.

Comment: It requires you to provide your password to keep malware from getting on your machine and sending out spam email without your knowledge. We all like that you have to provide your password.

Comment: What's your concern using a password? This is how most production applications send their email using SMTP. Alternatively, use a mail service (SendGrid)... but you still need to pass a password.

Comment: You need a password to your SMTP server in order to be able to use it to send mail.  If it didn't require a password, then it would be an open relay and could be used by others for launching SPAM attacks.

Comment: So, there is really no answer to this question.

Comment: If someone ask for your password, just never tell...

Comment: Ok thank you that makes more sense. I need to use an email in order to send an email and I need to be logged in. Thanks. At first glance it just seemed weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your password in your environment or in a `.env` file and then call it from your application using `process.env.PASSWORD`

This could help since your password won't be stored in the actual code.